# Black screen after suspend on ubuntu mate16.04 after going back to noveau

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, suspend

So im running ubuntu mate 16.04 on an asus rog 501g. I resently tried to switch to use the closed source nvidia driver from nouveau. After that i expirienced boot issues, so I switched back to the open source driver. Everything seems to be working fine, exept that now my laptop does not resume from suspend (only a black screen). This worked fine before.

Fixes that I have tried:

```
Purging nvidia

Reinstalling all the graphic drivers

Reinstalling Mate desktop

Upgrading to Linux kernel 4.8

Installing Nvidia driver v.367
```

Nothing has yet fixed the problem.

Does anyone have another fix or suggestion for this?

Graphix card: Nvidia Geoforce GTX 960m

Update:

Now running the propriatery nvidia-375 driver with linux kernel 4.7. Also installed bumblebee and modified bumblebee.conf. Installed bbswitch.
Blender runs with command: optirun blender, but not with primusrun.

Succsesfully installed CUDA. 
Hybernate works.

Problems that still persist:
suspend does not work.
External monitor with hdmi does not work.
Nvidia-settings is blank

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem. I'm using a MacBook Pro with a Benq24 as an external monitor. After a suspend, the Benq monitor shows a distorted view, with vertical bars through the display. Unplugging and reconnecting the monitor, or changing settings in the Settings>Appearance pane will fix the problem. 
The only 'permanent' solution I've found is to disable suspend altogether.

Comment: I use the same workaround now. The strangest thing to me is that suspend worked fine before I did any changes. I could still try to reinstall Ubuntu mate, but thats not the best option right now.

Comment: I've just replaced nouveau with the appropriate Nvidia driver, and the problem has gone away. This also fixed flickering at the monitor's native resolution.

Comment: Ok, I am a bit reluctant to try that, because installing the nvidia driver started all my problems. But Ill maby try it anyvay, if no other solution arises. Thanks!

Comment: I just searched for 'drivers' in the dash, which showed the 'Additional Drivers' panel.  Makes it easy to pick a new driver and install.

Comment: Installed the nvidia driver using these commands:                                                               sudo apt-add-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install nvidia-364 nvidia-prime                                                                                         still got black screen after suspend.

Comment: You've probably studied  [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia) already...

Comment: Yes I have. I also had to revert back to the noveau driver, since the nvidia drivers would not work with openGL, and this caused an issue with blender. Witch i need right now for work.

Answer (score 0):

Those Nvidia drivers are picky. You not only need to have the kernel, but you also need to have a package called `linux-headers-<your exact kernel version>`. You'd think it would be a part of the kernel update, but of late I've had issues. Both `4.13.0-38` and `4.13.0-39` gave me grief.

If you install that package and then try installing the NVIDIA drivers using the instructions user "b.wave" suggests, you will be in business. Unbricked me for sure when I ended up with a big mess on Tuesday when the `-39` kernel update did not install linux-headers for some strange reason and my video drivers went insane. Got the GUI back after switching to nouveau, but then ended up with a black screen of death on suspend.